Is this an algorithm that is theoretically polynomial, but practically exponential?
To solve a problem I have an algorithm $T(n)$ where,

the input of $n$ variables is transformed into $n$ numbers of size $>2^n!$,
then the algorithm requires $k.n^4$ arithmetic operations, where $k$ is significantly smaller than $n$

Note,

the transformation of the input can be done in polynomial time since the numbers only need to have $2^n$ numbers in specific patterns independent of the nature of the problem
the transformation is not dependent on the problem. We can construct a set $S$ of $m$ numbers in time $O(m)$, where $m > n$ and then the transformation is just a selection from $S$. With this the algorithm can then be run for all input sizes less than $m$

Example:
For $n = 10$, we need 10 numbers made by multiplying $2^{10} = 1024$ numbers. Numbers can repeat.
We can set $n_i$, where $i \in \{1,2...,10,11\}$, as follows,
$n_1 = (x_1*x_2...*x_{11})^{110}$
$n_2 = (x_1*x_3*x_5...*x_{11})^{180} * (x_2*x_4...*x_{10})$
...
$n_{11} = (x_1*x_3...*x_{11})^{60} * (x_2*x_4...*x_{10})^{50}$
where all $x_i$ are 11 numbers co-prime to each other, and then choose 10 numbers from this set of 11.
The transformation of the input can be done in linear time and the number of steps of $T(n)$ are polynomial in $n$. So theoretically it would be in $P$. Is this assumption correct?
However, after transformation the algorithm requires computation which I believe may not be practical as $n$ increases and in practical terms it won't be polynomial. Is this assumption also correct?
Edit: Realised I hadn't written this up properly. So corrected the language and added an example to clarify how the algorithm is to be setup.

The transformation is to create numbers by multiplying $2^n$ co-prime numbers in different combinations. The size of such a number will be similar to and more than factorial($2^n$).

No, because you can't write down a number of size $2^n!$ in polynomial time, so the running time is not polynomial in $n$.

I messed up with my algorithm description. Have edited it to hopefully better clarify and also provided an example. Its not necessary to write each digit after the transformation, just the representation of each number. However even with a compact representation, I am not able to work out how to compute the solution. The computation needs to be exact, so using logarithms may not work since that could lead to approximations unless the precision is kept large enough, which may itself become intractable.

N=4: If that number is bits then you need a big hard drive, still reasonably affordable. N=5: 16 sextillion terabytes. You can’t only not write it down in polynomial time, you can’t write it down.
